# How to insert jquery code into html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

The website that I am developing has banners, and when the site is viewed on mobile devices, the SWF banner doesn't show. In that case, I need to show an `<img>` tag, but the jQuery code doesn't work.

My template is something like this:

... (PHP + HTML code)

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
    if(!/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera     
    Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
</script>
```

... Show SWF banner

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
}
else {
</script>
```

... Show GIF banner

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
}
</script>
```

But it doesn't work. it shows up both of them instead.

Comment: You cannot break the script like that. This is not a server side language, but all of these get executed by the same browser. This is not PHP or ASP to do like this.

Comment: Open the browser console and try to solve the errors. Don't tell mobile don't have console use remote debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to do this:

**Javascript/JQuery:**

```
$(function() {
  if(!/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera     
    Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    $("#img").show();
  }else{
    $("#swf_banner").show();
  }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<img id="img" src=".." style="display:none;"/>
<object id="swf_banner" width="400" height="50" data="bookmark.swf" style="display:none;"></object>
```